# Wpf deleted selected rows from treelistview

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, treelistview

I have the following tree list view:

```
<dxg:TreeListControl Name="treeList" Grid.Row="7" Height="230" Margin="10,2,10,0">
    <dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Description" />
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Package" />
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Procedure" />
    </dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
    <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
        <dxg:TreeListView Name="treeListView" KeyFieldName="Id" ParentFieldName="ParentId" />
    </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <dxg:TreeListDragDropManager x:Name="dragDropManager" AllowDrag="True" />
    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
</dxg:TreeListControl>
```

My question is how to delete the selected rows from the tree list view.
Thanks

Comment: The right way to go is to use data binding and remove items from underlying data source.

Comment: That is want I want to do but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Assuming, that `TreeListControl` is `ItemsControl`, you need to bind its `ItemsSource` with some `ObservableCollection`, and remove items from that collection. It would be easier, if you'll post code, how do you fill items, and post a link to `TreeListControl` description.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [How to: Manually Control Drag and Drop](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11461) help-article that demonstrates how to customize Drag and Drop feature for the TreeList using Drag and Drop-related events.

The main idea of this article - if your TreeListControl is bound to the some collection:

```
treeList.ItemsSource = Stuff.GetStuff(); // ObservableCollection<Employee>
```

you can use the [TreeListDragDropManager.Drop](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11371) event to change some items from this collection (e.g. remove items):

```
void TreeListDragDropManager_Drop(object sender, 
    var employees = ((ObservableCollection<Employee>)treelist.ItemsSource);
    if(... some condition...){
        foreach (TreeListNode node in e.DraggedRows) {
            var employee = node.Content as Employee;
            employees.Remove(employee);
    }
}
```

[The complete sample project from the DevExpress Code Examples database.](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E3921)